PrimeNG 17 + Bootstrap can't add layers
I can't seem to make sense of this; I use primeNG17 + bootstrap in my project, I dumbed down my import to only use what makes sense in this case;
So here's my styles.scss

@layer bootstrap-r, primeng;

@layer bootstrap-r {
  @import "./assets/scss/argon-dashboard.scss";
  @import "./assets/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css";
  @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
  @import "../node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css";
}

@layer primeng {
  @import "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap4-light-blue/theme.css";
  @import "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
  @import "../node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.scss";
  @import "../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css";
}

@import "./variables.scss";


But my console says: 2: implicit outer layers: 0 primeNG, 1 bootstrap-r, and so bootstrap is taking precedence on primeNG and I can't achieve my desired design.
I mean, in my root folder, styles.scss, I have explicitly defined that there is layers, and in those layers, primeNG is 1.
But it is not what's happening, can someone enlighten me on what's wrong here ?
